# How to avoid port forwarding from vscode dev container

Tags: visual-studio-code, portforwarding, vscode-remote

I have a docker-from-docker development container setup. I am starting a application(Sim) docker from this development docker. After starting the application docker it prints some logs with some vnc link.

```
vscode ➜ /workspaces/vscode $ ./startSim.sh 
2023-03-28 09:31:40     [INFO ]: Starting Sim v6.0.0-15.0.425, please wait...
2023-03-28 09:31:40     [INFO ]: Sim is already running!
2023-03-28 09:31:40     [INFO ]: Sim docker IP address is: 172.17.0.3
2023-03-28 09:31:40     [INFO ]: URL to show Sim: http://localhost:6080/vnc.html
```

startSim.sh look like this

```
docker run -p 6080:6080 ...
```

When you click on the link (ctrl + click) http://localhost:6080/vnc.html in vscode dev container terminal, it opens http://localhost:6081/vnc.html in the browser. There is a portforward happening 6081-->6080

Since this docker-from-docker is a development container setup and the port 6080 port belong to Sim container. The port forwarding does not work.

Is there a setting that i can specify in my dev container (docker-from-docker) setup, so that when I ctrl + click on the link printed on the vscode dev container terminal it will not get forwarded.